# YoutubePlayerSupportFragment inside Viewpager

Tags: android, youtube-api

I have about 5 different videos from youtube and I want to put them into viewpager to slide them. Is there any solution for this with explanation, because I searched here and at different sites, but can't find something useful. Thank you for attention

Comment: See the YouTubeSample shipped with the release. Specifically look at the VideoListDemoActivity for how it uses the YouTubeThumbnailView for each cell.  That's what I'd recommend using for the ViewPager.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.reset()` on the old YouTubePlayer when the ViewPager is switched and then `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.initialize()`. This requires responding to the TabLayout's `onTabSelected` events which cant use `.setupWithViewPager` (which swallows both the ViewPager and TabLayouts view change events). This is roughly what's needed in the adapter (initialisePlayer and shutDownPlayer are called in response to tab changes, in the fragment that sets up the adapter, ViewPager and TabLayout):

```
private SparseArray<YouTubePlayerSupportFragment> fragments = new SparseArray<>(3);
private SparseArray<YouTubePlayer> players = new SparseArray<>(3);

@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(final int position) {
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment fragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
fragments.put(position, fragment);

return fragment;
}

public void initialisePlayer(final int position) {
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment fragment = fragments.get(position);
fragment.initialize(API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(final YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, final boolean b) {
players.put(position, youTubePlayer);
youTubePlayer.cueVideo(getVids()[position]);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(final YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, final YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
}
});

}

public void shutDownPlayer(int position) {
YouTubePlayer player = players.get(position);
if (player == null) {
return;
}
```